# Replae â€™ with an apostrphe (') in a textview

Tags: java, android

I'm downloading a JSON data format from an API. I keep seeing this symbol (â€™). Upon research, I have realized that it means an "apostrophe". This doesn't look appealing to users. How would I replace this weird character with a real apostrophe? Thank you

Example:

```
"title": "Apple engineers could walk away from FBIâ€™s iPhone demands",
      "kwic": "Current and former Apple employees say theyâ€™d rather quit than build an iPhone backdoor.",
      "content": "",
      "url": "http://www.cso.com.au/article/596281/apple-engineers-could-walk-away-from-fbi-iphone-demands/",
      "iurl": "http://cdn.cso.com.au/dimg/600x600//idg_sites/logos/cso_1.png",
      "domain": "www.cso.com.au",
      "author": "",
      "news": false,
      "votes": "1",
      "date": 1458389725517,
      "related": [

      ]
    }
```

Will be parsed into a `TextView`.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read UTF-8 encoded content as ISO 8859-15. Fix the encoding, not the results.

Comment: How would I do that? I am just making an http request with an API. The results are returned using json. Please elaborate

Comment: I'd start with the code that reads your http responses. It's also possible that the encoding problem is on the server side, though.

Comment: Show your code. You should indeed fix the encoding. But that's all.

Comment: Ok guys, this is just the results I received in a web browser. I made a call in my web browser, I then copied it and formatted it using a [online json viewer] (http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/). And I saw this problem. Wanted to figure it out before I started with real calling... Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this out, It will replace the symbol with apostrophe

```
       yourString.replaceAll("â€™","'");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is a good option, but I am guessing people might have better options.

Comment: what if some other badly encoded chars arrive? will create replacement for every? And `.replaceAll()` is designed for regex, here you should use `.replace()`

Comment: I tried .replace(), it only replaces the first occurence

Comment: No. replace() replaces all.

Comment: @ClintonYeboah how did you try `.replace()`? Actually, `String#replace()` replaces all occurrences as stated in the docs and many, many times tested by practice.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou am sorry. :(. My eyes must have deceived me first time. It does work